# Python tabula-py won't read pdf

Tags: python, pdf, subprocess, tabula

I am trying to extract tables from a series of PDF files but cannot make tabula-py work. I’ve been trying to use it through a Jupyter Notebook on a Windows OS. Unfortunately, I’m getting the same

> ‘FileNotFoundError’

every time I try to use the read_PDF().

From what I’ve found online so far, the error seems to be originated when trying to run the Tabula java file. I've got java properly installed.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
    from tabula import read_pdf
    df = read_pdf("https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java/raw/master/src/test/resources/technology/tabula/arabic.pdf")
```

Error message:

```
    FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-78-956ad4697ff7> in <module>()
          1 from tabula import read_pdf
    ----> 2 df = read_pdf("https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java/raw/master/src/test/resources/technology/tabula/arabic.pdf")

    C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tabula\wrapper.py in read_pdf(input_path, **kwargs)
         64 
         65     try:
    ---> 66         output = subprocess.check_output(args)
         67     finally:
         68         if is_url:

    C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
        624 
        625     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    --> 626                **kwargs).stdout
        627 
        628 

    C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
        691         kwargs['stdin'] = PIPE
        692 
    --> 693     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
        694         try:
        695             stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)

    C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds)
        945                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
        946                                 errread, errwrite,
    --> 947                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
        948         except:
        949             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

    C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
       1222                                          env,
       1223                                          cwd,
    -> 1224                                          startupinfo)
       1225             finally:
       1226                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe
```

Comment: you need to give more details if you'd like to get some answer. Please provide working code sample to reproduce your problem

Comment: Thanks @PawelMiech. I just added the code I'm trying to run. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduce this problem without setting PATH environment for java.exe. Make sure to set PATH for Java. See also:
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: Thanks a lot, @chezou. It’s running fine now from a terminal window but I still get the same error when running on a Jupyter Notebook. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I do it like this, and run code

1. `pip install tabula-py`
2. `conda install tabula-py`
3. `conda install java`
4. `from tabula import read_pdf`
5. `import pandas as pd`
6. `dt = read_pdf('file.pdf', encoding = 'latin1', pages ='all', nospreadsheet = True)`

Good luck to you..

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = tabula.read_pdf("Danamon - FS - FY-18.pdf", pages = i, guess = False)
```

It worked for me using the additional argument `guess = False`

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that Windows can find the Java compiler and interpreter:
Select Start -> Computer -> System Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables -> System variables -> PATH.
[ In Vista, select Start -> My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System variables -> PATH. ]

[ In Windows XP, Select Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System variables -> PATH. ]

Prepend C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin; to the beginning of the PATH variable.
Click OK three times.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue in Ubuntu.

First, check the version of the JDK and JRE that are installed on your machine by running java --version and javac --version. Each should have a version greater than 7.

Then use pip3 to install tabula.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not able to find the PDF file. So first look for PDF file by providing absolute or relative path.

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
print(os.listdir('Other'))

#Locating PDF file with searching and then joining absolute and relative path
file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test.pdf')
```